# JPanel components disappear after trying to refresh them

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to make it so that I have two panels in a frame. One displays 4 cards and the other a button. When the button is clicked the four cards are chosen again randomly. The cards are not showing up when I initialize the program or when I click refresh.
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix this ?

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    public MyFrame(){
        super("Random Cards");
        CardPanel cardPanel = new CardPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton jbtRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        buttonPanel.add(jbtRefresh);
        add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                cardPanel.refresh();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class CardPanel extends JPanel{
        JLabel l1;
        JLabel l2;
        JLabel l3;
        JLabel l4;

        void CardPanel(){
            refresh();
        }

        void refresh(){
            l1 =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image/card/" + (int)(1 + Math.random() * 54) + ".png"));
            l2 =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image/card/" + (int)(1 + Math.random() * 54) + ".png"));
            l3 =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image/card/" + (int)(1 + Math.random() * 54) + ".png"));
            l4 =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image/card/" + (int)(1 + Math.random() * 54) + ".png"));
            removeAll();
            add(l1);
            add(l2);
            add(l3);
            add(l4);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to access the `cardPanel` variable in the `ActionListener`. In order to do that `cardPanel` has to be `final`

Comment: What are you talking about? `final` is a constant modifier.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi He is trying to access a variable in an `anonymous inner class`. In order to do that the variable has to be `final`

Comment: So? `cardPanel` is defined in the constructor.

Comment: @Malik Brahimi This thing is unrelated to his question, I'm just saying that he's code won't compile because he is accessing `cardPanel` inside the `actionPerformed` method

Comment: Listen. The anonymous inner class can access the `cardPanel` because `cardPanel` is in the same scope in the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69264/discussion-between-titus-and-malik-brahimi).

Comment: The code does compile just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Call `revalidate` before `repaint` when calling `refresh`...

**Longer, more appropriate answer**

Consider using a `CardLayout` instead.  See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

**Also...**

- Make sure you are creating/modifying you UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.
- You might consider making a `Card` class, that extends from something like `JPanel`, which is responsible for showing a particular card.  This way you could simply calculate the random card values you need and continuously update the pre-existing instances, rather than creating new instances each time. Generally, it will run faster and be more efficent

*Nit pick*: You should avoid extending your UI's directly from top level containers like `JFrame`, they tend to lock you into a single use case and make it difficult to reuse or extend in the future.  You're not really adding any new functionality to the frame anyway